# Get File Url from a Lookup Column REST API

Tags: 2013, rest, file

I have a lookup column that correlates to a background image in my presentation layer. Is it possible to expose the URL to the actual file via the `$expand` mechanism using **REST**?

**Example REST URI**

```
https://my.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=Title,FileRef,Document_x0020_Image/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=Document_x0020_Image
```

If I do a separate **REST** call to the actual `Document Image` list there are a couple properties that look useful, the most useful being `ServerRelativeUrl`. But I get an invalid request error trying to `$expand` on this property. See below.

> The query to field '`Document_x0020_Image/ServerRelativeUrl`' is not valid.

I'd very much appreciate any help with this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ListItem` resource  does not expose `ServerRelativeUrl` property, you could use `FileRef` property instead. But still it does **not** seem possible to accomplish using SharePoint **2013** REST since `FileRef` property could not be retrieved for a *projected* field.

And again SharePoint **2010** REST comes to the rescue!

The following query returns Lookup field file url:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Documents?$select=DocumentImage/Name,DocumentImage/Path&$expand=DocumentImage
```

where `DocumentImage` is a Lookup field

The expression to construct a File url:

```
fileUrl = DocumentImage.Path + '/' + DocumentImage.Name;
```

**Example**

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var selectFields = ['Title','DocumentImage/Name','DocumentImage/Path'];
var expandFields = ['DocumentImage'];
getListItems(webUrl,'Documents',selectFields,expandFields)
    .done(function(data){
         for(var i = 0; i< data.d.results.length;i++) {
             var image = data.d.results[i].DocumentImage;
             if(image != null) {
               var imageUrl = image.Path + '/' + image.Name; 
               console.log(imageUrl);           
             }
         }
    });
```

where

```
function executeRequest(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    if (typeof headers == 'undefined' || headers == null){
        headers = {};
    }
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}

function getListItems(webUrl,listName,selectFields, expandFields){
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName;
    endpointUrl+= '?$select=' + selectFields.join(",");
    endpointUrl+= '&$expand=' + expandFields.join(",");
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'GET');
}
```